# Delete an Array Field (Array contains object)

Tags: java

I am trying to delete a field in an array.
The array contains objects of type `Person` (`Person` contains firstname, lastname, birthdate and ID).

My intention was to look up each array field and compare the input ID with all the array fields. When I find the right one, I will set it to `null`.

But I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And I don't know why.

```
public static void removePerson(Person[] container) {
    TextIO.putln("Enter ID of person to be removed");
    int index = TextIO.getInt();

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < container.length ; i ++) {
        if (container[i].id == index)
            container[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In all likelihood, one of `container`'s elements are `null`. We can't help with only the code you gave us, as `container` isn't set up there. Please provide us with an [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Just print all stacktrace and you will find out the reason. You should change this line: `if (container[i].id == index)` to `if (container[i] != null && container[i].id == index)`.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely case is your array isn't full, so some container array entries are null, and `container[i].id` is what triggers the null pointer exception. Replace your test with

`if ((container[i] != null) && (container[i].id==index))`

and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the row

```
 container[i].id == index
```

when you have already "removed" (marked null) a previous container you could get a NullPointerException

replace to

```
  if (container[i]!=null && container[i].id == index)
```